# Deixar todos LI com a altura do maior usando CSS

Tags: html, css, css3, css-display

Tenho alguns elementos `<li>` que oriento para ficar `inline-block`. Porém, como o conteudo de cada `<li>` é diferente, eles acabam ficando com ALTURA diferente. Tipo assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, o correto é que o `<li>` com menos conteúdo pegue a mesma altura do `<li>` maior, e ficar alinhado, tipo assim:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como resolver isso?

Comment: coloque se código css e html

Comment: CSS do LI: width: 200px; position: relative; height: 100%; border: 1px solid #ccc; padding: 5px; text-align: center; display: inline-block;

Comment: Até onde eu sei `height: 100%` só funciona se os elementos superiores tiverem altura definida.

Comment: coloca o seu código para podermos ajudar

Comment: De todas as linhas apenas com CSS não sei se é possível, mas deixar do mesmo tamanho por linha você pode conseguir utilizando `flex`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deixar TODOS os blocos do mesmo tamanho utilizando apenas CSS não sei se é possível (desconheço) já que cada linha passa a se tornar independente, mas cada elemento de uma linha tem uma certa ligação e podem ser usadas como parâmetro para manter todos os outros (da mesma linha) com o mesmo tamanho.

A forma mais fácil de conseguir esse resultado é utilizando o Flex:

```css
ul{
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

li{
  width: 25%;
  border: 5px solid black;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 3px; 
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Commodi rerum doloremque laborum? </li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Et quasi corporis sed fugit quibusdam, possimus ipsam animi ab molestias. Eos qui id sint mollitia amet officiis, commodi natus officia libero.</li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</li>
</ul>
```

o `display: flex` por padrão já deixará todos os elementos com o mesmo tamanho, mas você perde o controle sobre sua largura ele tentará deixar tudo na mesma linha, desrespeitando a largura definida ou os limites da página ou elemento pai, que pode ser resolvido utilizando o `flex-wrap`, que permite quebrar a linha assim que os elementos ultrapassem a tela.

Fica aí uma alternativa, porém não resolve 100%.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode definir a propriedade `min-height` um valor de acordo com o conteúdo. Ex.: se sua li maior possui 200px, defina:

```
   li {
       min-height: 200px;
    }
```

Comment: Elementos com muito conteúdo podem passar de 200px de altura, enquanto elementos com pouco conteúdo ficariam com exato 200px. Isso só resolveria o problema se a altura definida é, com certeza, maior que a altura do maior elemento e isso não há como garantir.

Comment: O valor de 200px foi só um exemplo. Se é pra todos os elemento ficarem iguais, de qualquer jeito elementos com pouco conteúdo ficaria com espaço vazio. Acredito que, mesmo com conteúdo dinâmico, há um limite para o elemento, caso contrário, não ficaria bom visualmente.

Comment: Mas se todos os elementos possuírem pouco conteúdo, tambẽm não ficará legal, pois todos terão o espaço em branco.

Comment: Mas é isso que o usuário quer, ele quer que o tamanho das <li> fiquem iguais.

Comment: Quer que fiquem da mesma altura que a maior, mas se nenhuma ultrapassar os 200px, todas ficarão com 200px, ou seja, da mesma altura, mas sobrando um espaço em branco na página.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar um javascript para isso

Seleciona o elemento de maior alutura e retorna o valor

```
function getMaiorTamanho(element) {
    var maiorTamanho = 0;
    $(element).each(function(){
        var height = $(this).css('min-height');
        height = parseFloat(height.replace('px',''));
        if(maiorTamanho<height)
        {
            maiorTamanho = height;
        }
    });
    return maiorTamanho
}
```

Como usar

```
$('.card-footer p').each(function(){ 
      $(this).css('min-height',getMaiorTamanho('.card-footer p')); 
});
```

Espero que ajude